# Pairwise cross product by pytorch & its precision problem

Tags: pytorch

I'm a student who just started study pytorch.

I hope to generate pairwise cross product matrix.

Example is below.

```
x=torch.Tensor([[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]) # 2*3
y=torch.Tensor([[2,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,2]]) # 3*3

#what I want to get is below using torch.cross

z=torch.Tensor([[[0,0,0],[0,0,2],[0,-2,0]],\
                 [0,0,-2],[0,0,0],[2,0,0]]]) # 2*3*3
#So I write code

tmp_x=0*y+x.unsqueeze(1)# 2*3*3 , horrible coding.. please modify this.
tmp_y=y+0*x.unsqueeze(1)
z=torch.cross(tmp_x,tmp_y,dim=-1)
```

I think my code is not good. May I have advice for more good code?

And there is precision problem, when I use it for float type. Cross product between a vector and itself is not zero-vector. 
 When I print each matrix in above code like below, in this case x=y,

```
print x
print y
print '====='
print tmp_x
print tmp_y
print '====='
print z
```

then I got result.

```
tensor([[ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
        [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
        [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037]])
tensor([[ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
        [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
        [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037]])
=======
tensor([[[ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
         [ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
         [ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010]],

        [[-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
         [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
         [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091]],

        [[ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037],
         [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037],
         [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037]]])
tensor([[[ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
         [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
         [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037]],

        [[ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
         [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
         [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037]],

        [[ 0.2957,  1.6024, -0.1010],
         [-1.4755,  0.1937, -0.6091],
         [ 1.3540,  0.7203,  0.4037]]])
=======
tensor([[[ 5.0209e-09, -2.8436e-10, -1.0191e-08],
         [-9.5639e-01,  3.2915e-01,  2.4217e+00],
         [ 7.1970e-01, -2.5616e-01, -1.9567e+00]],

        [[ 9.5639e-01, -3.2915e-01, -2.4217e+00],
         [ 6.0023e-10, -2.4257e-08,  1.3432e-08],
         [ 5.1692e-01, -2.2897e-01, -1.3251e+00]],

        [[-7.1970e-01,  2.5616e-01,  1.9567e+00],
         [-5.1692e-01,  2.2897e-01,  1.3251e+00],
         [ 9.2649e-09,  5.7705e-09, -4.0787e-09]]])
```

z[0,0,:] must be zero vector, but it is not. What did I wrong?

Comment: I pasted your code into a python prompt and got `z[0, 0, :]==tensor([0., 0., 0.])`. What version of PyTorch are you using?